# Automatically set attribute values ​for a layer based on proximity relations to another layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, fields-attributes, proximity

Is it possible to automatically set attribute values for a layer based on proximity relationships to another layer in QGIS?

This is a more generic question with a variety of applications, so here is a concrete example: I have a road network (linestrings) with attributes (among others) `road_name` and `road_sgmnt_id` and a point layer with building sites also with attributes `road_name` and `road_sgmnt_id` (also among others). What I would like to do *during digitizing a building site* is to find the closest (proximity relationship) road segment, retrieve certain attribute values and insert them into the building site form as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

I must confess I am not quite experienced with user defined forms in QGIS (ui-files) but I think such form with some python logic defined behind it could do the trick.

Hint: Since the datasource is not necessarily a database, and if, the form could not be auto-filled this way during digitizing, a trigger function would only be a second option (if any).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution that works fine for me using a *Python Init function* for an autogenerated form, setup in Layer Properties|Fields like this:

[image]

The python init code provided in the dialog that finds the nearest road segments and autofills the appropriate fields in the form is the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLineEdit
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.gui import *

def my_form_open(dialog, layer, feature):
    #access road network layer
    road_lyr = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(u'road_network')[0]

    #create index and insert features
    road_lyr_index = QgsSpatialIndex()
    for f in road_lyr.getFeatures():
        road_lyr_index.insertFeature(f)

    #nearest neighbor expects QgsPoint as parameter
    geom = feature.geometry().asPoint()

    #find nearest road line segments
    fids = road_lyr_index.nearestNeighbor(geom, 1)
    req = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(fids)
    res = [(f['osm_id'], f['osm_name']) for f in road_lyr.getFeatures(req)]

    #autofill form depending on result
    if len(res) == 1:
        str_id, str_name = res[0]

        le_osm_id = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit, "str_osm_id")
        le_str = dialog.findChild(QLineEdit, "str")

        le_osm_id.setText(str(str_id))
        le_str.setText(str_name)
    else:
        le_osm_id.setText('0')
        le_str.setText('undef\'d, enter manually')
```

Note that the index creation takes some time for large network datasets, my dataset is ~18k features, index creation slightly above 1 sec.